# How to change the image attribute of a capscreen using AUTOIT

Tags: image-processing, autoit

I am new to autoit and not sure how to change the brightness and contrast of the screencap before/after the image is saved on my harddrive? I found this function online (WinAPI_CreateColorAdjustment) but not sure how to integrate it with screencap.

My codes are:

```
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

$POSITION1=GUICtrlRead(1619)
$POSITION2=GUICtrlRead(210)
$POSITION3=GUICtrlRead(1900)
$POSITION4=GUICtrlRead(300)
_ScreenCapture_Capture(@ScriptDir & "\screencap.png",$POSITION1,$POSITION2,$POSITION3,$POSITION4)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for the **_WinAPI_CreateColorAdjustment** function:

```
#include <APIGdiConstants.au3>
#include <ComboConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GDIPlus.au3>
#include <GUIComboBox.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <SliderConstants.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIGdi.au3>
#include <WinAPIShPath.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Opt('GUICloseOnESC', 0)
Opt('TrayAutoPause', 0)

Global $g_aDefault[11] = [10000, 10000, 10000, 0, 10000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Global $g_aAdjust = $g_aDefault

_GDIPlus_Startup()

Local $hObj, $hSrc, $W, $H, $sData
While 1
    $sData = FileOpenDialog('Load Image', @ScriptDir & '\Extras', 'Image Files (*.bmp;*.dib;*.gif;*.jpg;*.tif)|All Files (*.*)', 1 + 2)
    If @error Then Exit

    $hObj = _GDIPlus_ImageLoadFromFile($sData)
    If $hObj Then
        $hSrc = _GDIPlus_BitmapCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap($hObj)
        $W = _GDIPlus_ImageGetWidth($hObj)
        $H = _GDIPlus_ImageGetHeight($hObj)
        _GDIPlus_ImageDispose($hObj)
        If $hSrc Then
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
    EndIf
    MsgBox(BitOR($MB_ICONERROR, $MB_SYSTEMMODAL), 'Error', 'Unable to load image.')
WEnd

Local $hForm = GUICreate(_WinAPI_PathStripPath($sData), $W, $H)
GUICtrlCreatePic('', 0, 0, $W, $H)
GUICtrlSetState(-1, $GUI_DISABLE)
Local $hPic = GUICtrlGetHandle(-1)
Global $g_hTool = GUICreate('Adjustments', 303, 484, -1, -1, BitOR($WS_CAPTION, $WS_POPUP), 0, $hForm)
GUICtrlCreateGraphic(0, 0, 303, 436)
GUICtrlSetState(-1, $GUI_DISABLE)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
GUICtrlCreateGraphic(0, 436, 303, 1)
GUICtrlSetState(-1, $GUI_DISABLE)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xDFDFDF)
Global $g_aidSlider[9][6] = [[0, 0, 'Red', 25, 650, 100], [0, 0, 'Green', 25, 650, 100], [0, 0, 'Blue', 25, 650, 100], [0, 0, 'Black', 0, 400, 10], [0, 0, 'White', 600, 1000, 10], [0, 0, 'Contrast', -100, 100, 1], [0, 0, 'Brightness', -100, 100, 1], [0, 0, 'Colorfulness', -100, 100, 1], [0, 0, 'Tint', -100, 100, 1]]
For $i = 0 To 8
    GUICtrlCreateLabel($g_aidSlider[$i][2] & ':', 10, 21 + $i * 31, 60, 14, $SS_RIGHT)
    GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
    $g_aidSlider[$i][2] = GUICtrlCreateInput('', 243, 18 + $i * 31, 49, 19, BitOR($ES_CENTER, $ES_READONLY))
    GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 9.3, 400, 0, 'Arial')
    GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
    $g_aidSlider[$i][0] = GUICtrlCreateSlider(71, 19 + $i * 31, 170, 20, BitOR($TBS_BOTH, $TBS_NOTICKS))
    GUICtrlSetLimit(-1, $g_aidSlider[$i][4], $g_aidSlider[$i][3])
    $g_aidSlider[$i][1] = GUICtrlGetHandle(-1)
    GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
Next
GUICtrlCreateLabel('Illuminant:', 10, 310, 60, 14, $SS_RIGHT)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
Global $g_idCombo = GUICtrlCreateCombo('', 77, 306, 158, 160, $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
Local $aLight = StringSplit('Default|Tungsten lamp|Noon sunlight|NTSC daylight|Normal print|Bond paper print|Standard daylight|Northern daylight|Cool white lamp', '|')
For $i = 1 To $aLight[0]
    _GUICtrlComboBox_AddString(-1, $aLight[$i])
Next
GUICtrlCreateLabel('Filters:', 10, 347, 60, 14, $SS_RIGHT)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
Global $g_aidCheck[3]
$g_aidCheck[0] = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox('Negative (invert colors)', 77, 343, 131, 21)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
$g_aidCheck[1] = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox('Logarithmic', 77, 368, 76, 21)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
$g_aidCheck[2] = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox('Preview', 11, 401, 60, 21)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
GUICtrlSetState(-1, $GUI_CHECKED)
Local $aidButton[2]
$aidButton[0] = GUICtrlCreateButton('Reset', 136, 448, 75, 25)
$aidButton[1] = GUICtrlCreateButton('Save...', 218, 448, 75, 25)
_Reset()
GUICtrlSetState($g_aidSlider[0][0], $GUI_FOCUS)
GUIRegisterMsg($WM_HSCROLL, 'WM_HSCROLL')
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hForm)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $g_hTool)

While 1
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case 0
            ContinueLoop
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $aidButton[0]
            _Reset()
        Case $aidButton[1]
            GUISetState(@SW_DISABLE, $hForm)
            $sData = FileSaveDialog('Save Image', @WorkingDir, 'Image Files (*.bmp;*.dib;*.gif;*.jpg;*.tif)|All Files (*.*)', 2 + 16, @ScriptDir & '\MyImage.jpg', $g_hTool)
            GUICtrlSetState($aidButton[1], $GUI_FOCUS)
            GUISetState(@SW_ENABLE, $hForm)
            If Not $sData Then
                ContinueLoop
            EndIf
            $hObj = _GDIPlus_BitmapCreateFromHBITMAP(_SendMessage($hPic, $STM_GETIMAGE))
            If $hObj Then
                If _GDIPlus_ImageSaveToFile($hObj, $sData) Then
                    $sData = 0
                EndIf
                _GDIPlus_ImageDispose($hObj)
            EndIf
            If $sData Then
                MsgBox(BitOR($MB_ICONERROR, $MB_SYSTEMMODAL), 'Error', 'Unable to save image.')
            EndIf
        Case $g_aidCheck[0]
            If GUICtrlRead($g_aidCheck[0]) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
                $g_aAdjust[9] = BitOR($g_aAdjust[9], $CA_NEGATIVE)
            Else
                $g_aAdjust[9] = BitAND($g_aAdjust[9], BitNOT($CA_NEGATIVE))
            EndIf
            _Update()
        Case $g_aidCheck[1]
            If GUICtrlRead($g_aidCheck[1]) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
                $g_aAdjust[9] = BitOR($g_aAdjust[9], $CA_LOG_FILTER)
            Else
                $g_aAdjust[9] = BitAND($g_aAdjust[9], BitNOT($CA_LOG_FILTER))
            EndIf
            _Update()
        Case $g_aidCheck[2]
            If GUICtrlRead($g_aidCheck[2]) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
                _SetBitmapAdjust($hPic, $hSrc, $g_aAdjust)
            Else
                _SetBitmapAdjust($hPic, $hSrc)
            EndIf
        Case $g_idCombo
            $sData = _GUICtrlComboBox_GetCurSel($g_idCombo)
            If $g_aAdjust[10] <> $sData Then
                $g_aAdjust[10] = $sData
                _Update()
            EndIf
    EndSwitch
WEnd

Func _Reset()
    $g_aAdjust = $g_aDefault
    For $i = 0 To 8
        GUICtrlSetData($g_aidSlider[$i][0], $g_aAdjust[$i] / $g_aidSlider[$i][5])
        GUICtrlSetData($g_aidSlider[$i][2], $g_aAdjust[$i])
    Next
    _GUICtrlComboBox_SetCurSel($g_idCombo, $g_aAdjust[10])
    If BitAND($g_aAdjust[9], $CA_LOG_FILTER) Then
        GUICtrlSetState($g_aidCheck[1], $GUI_CHECKED)
    Else
        GUICtrlSetState($g_aidCheck[1], $GUI_UNCHECKED)
    EndIf
    If BitAND($g_aAdjust[9], $CA_NEGATIVE) Then
        GUICtrlSetState($g_aidCheck[0], $GUI_CHECKED)
    Else
        GUICtrlSetState($g_aidCheck[0], $GUI_UNCHECKED)
    EndIf
    _Update()
EndFunc   ;==>_Reset

Func _SetBitmapAdjust($hWnd, $hBitmap, $aAdjust = 0)
    If Not IsHWnd($hWnd) Then
        $hWnd = GUICtrlGetHandle($hWnd)
        If Not $hWnd Then
            Return 0
        EndIf
    EndIf

    Local $tAdjust = 0
    If IsArray($aAdjust) Then
        $tAdjust = _WinAPI_CreateColorAdjustment($aAdjust[9], $aAdjust[10], $aAdjust[0], $aAdjust[1], $aAdjust[2], $aAdjust[3], $aAdjust[4], $aAdjust[5], $aAdjust[6], $aAdjust[7], $aAdjust[8])
    EndIf
    $hBitmap = _WinAPI_AdjustBitmap($hBitmap, -1, -1, $HALFTONE, $tAdjust)
    If @error Then
        Return 0
    EndIf
    Local $hPrev = _SendMessage($hWnd, $STM_SETIMAGE, $IMAGE_BITMAP, $hBitmap)
    If $hPrev Then
        _WinAPI_DeleteObject($hPrev)
    EndIf
    $hPrev = _SendMessage($hWnd, $STM_GETIMAGE)
    If $hPrev <> $hBitmap Then
        _WinAPI_DeleteObject($hBitmap)
    EndIf
    Return 1
EndFunc   ;==>_SetBitmapAdjust

Func _Update()
    If GUICtrlRead($g_aidCheck[2]) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
        _SetBitmapAdjust($hPic, $hSrc, $g_aAdjust)
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_Update

Func WM_HSCROLL($hWnd, $iMsg, $wParam, $lParam)
    #forceref $iMsg, $wParam

    Switch $hWnd
        Case $g_hTool
            For $i = 0 To 8
                If $g_aidSlider[$i][1] = $lParam Then
                    $g_aAdjust[$i] = $g_aidSlider[$i][5] * GUICtrlRead($g_aidSlider[$i][0])
                    GUICtrlSetData($g_aidSlider[$i][2], $g_aAdjust[$i])
                    _Update()
                    ExitLoop
                EndIf
            Next
    EndSwitch
    Return $GUI_RUNDEFMSG
EndFunc   ;==>WM_HSCROLL
```

Note: this function seems **not work with PNG format**, so you should save screenshots as JPG or BMP.